# Adding signals on the candle chart

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly, mplfinance

I would like to plot signals on my chart is there is a way to do it on candle stick?
I did the following and got stuck :(

```
!pip install yfinance
!pip install mplfinance
import yfinance as yf
import mplfinance as mpf
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd 

df=yf.download('BTC-USD',start='2008-01-04',end='2021-06-3',interval='1d')

buy=np.where((df['Close'] > df['Open']) & (df['Close'].shift(1) < df['Open'].shift(1),1,0)

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (20,10))
mpf.plot(df,figsize=(20,12),type ='candle',volume=True);

# any idea how to add the signal?
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
import yfinance as yf
import mplfinance as mpf
import numpy as np 

df = yf.download('BTC-USD', start='2008-01-04', end='2021-06-3', interval='1d').tail(50)

buy = np.where((df['Close'] > df['Open']) & (df['Close'].shift(1) < df['Open'].shift(1)), 1, np.nan) * 0.95 * df['Low']

apd = [mpf.make_addplot(buy, scatter=True, markersize=100, marker=r'$\Uparrow$', color='green')]

mpf.plot(df, type='candle', volume=True, addplot=apd)
```

I just added `.tail()` for better visualization.

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply for some reason I get the arrows way down. I will attach a picture

Answer (score 0):

You place signals on the plot using the "make additional plot" api: `mpf.make_addplot(data,**kwargs)`.  The data that you pass in to `make_addplot` must be the same length as your original candlestick dataframe (so that mplfinance can line it up appropriately with the candlesticks).  If you do not want to plot a signal at every location you simply fill the data with `nan` values except where you ***do*** want to plot a signal.

The return value from `ap = mpf.make_addplot()` is then passed into `mpf.plot(df,addplot=ap)` using the `addplot` kwarg.

You can see many examples in [**this tutorial on adding your own technical studies to plots**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/addplot.ipynb).

Take the time (maybe 10 minutes or so) to go carefully through the entire tutorial.  It will be time well spent.