# mplfinance - how to display numbers on top of each candle stick

Tags: mplfinance

How can I display letters or numbers on each candle stick on mplfinance? For example, I want to show 0 (for green bars) and 1 (for red bars) on top of each candle stick, instead of marks.

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of ways to do this.  You can do it with `Axes.text()` or with `Axes.annotate()` as noted in these examples:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/70342687/1639359
- https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/issues/387#issuecomment-828135146

However, probably the easiest solution is to [**use `mpf.make_addplot()`**](https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/addplot.ipynb) to create a **`type=scatter`** plot where you want the numbers to appear, and then pass in a *sequence of markers* for the `marker=` kwarg (of make_addplot), and use [**Mathtext markers**](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/marker_reference.html) for the markers (for example "$1$" is a '1', etc.)

### [Click here for example code.](https://nbviewer.org/github/matplotlib/mplfinance/blob/master/examples/scratch_pad/scatter_multiple_markers.ipynb)

---

Other discussions that *may* be worth reading through:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/68035851/1639359
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/68035949/1639359
- https://github.com/matplotlib/mplfinance/issues/97